# Magic trackpad 2 hapic feedback not working

Tags: macos, bluetooth, monterey, magic-trackpad

My Magic Trackpad 2 doesn't "click", there's no haptic feedback.

If I turn it off, wait a minute before turning back on, it will start working for about 30s, and then stop again. I'm still able to use it as usual, there's just no "click".

I have another Magic Trackpad 2 at work, that one is fine. No problems at all. They're both running the same firmware too `1.0.7`.

And if I forget the device, turn it off and back on, the haptic click works indefinitely (until I connect it back to my computer).

Insanity.

So far I've tried...

1. "forgetting" the bluetooth device
2. Computer restart
3. Draining the trackpad battery and recharging
4. PRAM reset
5. Wired connection to trackpad (lightning cable)

My current theory is that there's a corrupt config somewhere on my machine which I haven't been able to clear. But I'm not sure if that exists or where it would be.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Same issue. Did the trackpad end up working somehow?